# What is the preferred way to handle basic arrays in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I am in the processing of learning python after using Matlab for years. I've run into a snag and I'm not finding much help in my google search.

I would like to know the best way to handle basic arrays.  Should I be using numpy, scipy, array, numarray, or something else?

For example, take the following Matlab code.

```
a = rand(10,1)
b = rand(10,1)


c = b > 0.5
d = a .* b
e = a + b
f = mean(a)
g = sum(b)
```

What would be the best way to convert this to python?

Comment: Numpy is part of SciPy, it supersedes Numarray, and the built-in `array` is very rudimentary support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely go with NumPy if you'll be doing math with arrays of numbers; there's even a [migration guide](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) for MATLAB users.

NumPy does a lot of the same array-broadcasting that MATLAB does, so it should be pretty natural to use. Your code can be written as:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10,1)
b = np.random.rand(10,1)
c = b > 0.5
d = a * b # Note that * in NumPy is always elementwise (use .dot for matrix multiplication)
e = a + b
f = a.mean() # Can also use np.mean(a)
g = b.sum() # Can also use np.sum(b)
```

Comment: I was looking at that.  I just wanted to make sure NumPy wasn't overkill for what I was trying to do.

Comment: Well, depends on what you want to do, of course. In your example, you could use regular Python lists, but then you don't get any of the nice broadcasting shortcuts that NumPy provides (e.g. you'd have to do `d = [x*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]` instead of `d = a*b` if `a` and `b` were ordinary Python lists).

Comment: And, of course, if you want to do anything remotely fancy like `fft`, plotting, matrix operations, etc. then you really must use NumPy.